# How to Push a Navigation Controller after instantiate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I want to push my Navigation Controller but I get :
`pushing a navigation controller is not supported`

[image]

I can't instantiate my TableView.

This is my code :

```
let newViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as! UINavigationController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

So there is a way to push the NavigationController ?

Comment: You can't push navigation controller.You can push your tableviewcontrolller.

Comment: navigationController should be presented always or set to root controller  , why you are trying to do that , and why you don't directly push tableviewcontrolller to current navigation controller

Comment: Why can't you have tableview controller as navigation controller's root view controller & hide navigation bar if not required.. then you will be able to push second controller on selection of any cell.

Comment: @Ellen I'm not sure to know how to do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your tableVC as root view controller of navigation controller :

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var tableViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewController") as! HomeViewController
let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController)
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationVC
```

Now in TableViewController ,to hide navigation bar

```
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Then you can push another view controller like you mentioned

```
let newViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as! UINavigationController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: you can't push a navigation controller

Comment: NavigationController is container type not content type. UIViewController is content type, so you should push a content controller in container.

Answer (score 1):

**Here we can see the first line means that is the stack of view controller to provide drill down,** So you have to push minimum one UIViewController object in the stack or make the root of the stack to any view controller for navigation controller.

**From apple document.**

> A navigation controller manages a stack of view controllers to provide
>   a drill-down interface for hierarchical content. The view hierarchy of
>   a navigation controller is self contained. It is composed of views
>   that the navigation controller manages directly and views that are
>   managed by content view controllers you provide. Each content view
>   controller manages a distinct view hierarchy, and the navigation
>   controller coordinates the navigation between these view hierarchies.

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

Comment: So I instantiate my UIViewController then i push my UITableView in the stack of the UIViewController then I show my UITableView ?

Comment: You have to initiate TableViewController and make the rootviewcontroller of the UINavigationController after that you can push any viewcontroller in this navigationcontroller.